# Mongoose Throw Error When Non Existing Key is Present

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, mongoose

I have a code where I am updating my schema object with request body. I have applied validation rules on the schema. The problem is, I want the schema to throw an error when there's a non existing field in the request body. Non existing key doesn't save to the database as I want but I want to throw some error instead of saving the object. Schema:

```
const peopleSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        fullname: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "fullname is required"],
            validate: [(value) => isAlpha(value, "en-US", {ignore: " "}), "name should be alphabetic only"],
        },
        phone: {
            type: String,
            validate: [isPhone, "please enter a valid phone number"],
        },
        address: String,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

Code to update person:

```
router.put("/:id", checkUser, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const user = req.currentUser;
        const person = user.people.id(id);
        
        person.set(req.body);

        const response = await user.save();
        res.json({ response });
    } catch (err) {
        next(new BadRequestError(err));
    }
});
```

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi okay, when I test it, I'll proceed. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi, it didn't work. But I'm doing it as it is. Just ignore extra fields and save record.

Answer (score 0):

for validation there are two way based on `callback` and `async` approache ,
because your code is based on async/await you must to use `validateSync()` like the following code:

```
let errors = user.validateSync()//check validation
if(errors){
     console.log(errors)
     throw errors;//handle your error 
     }
const response =  await user.save()
```

in callback method :

```
 user.save(function(err,response){ 
    if (err){ 
        console.log(err); 
        //handle error
       } 
     else{ 
         console.log(response) 
         res.json({ response });
      } 
 })
```